# REGEX in Validation Rule

Tags: validation-rule, regular-expressions

I have a custom field on an object which should allow values based on the following JavaScript REGEX.

```
/[^\sa-zA-Z0-9.,:?;%/()'!""-]/g
```

Can anyone help me how to use this REGEX in validation rule ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should screen with `\` such literals as `\`, `'`, `"` and use `REGEX(text, regex_text)` in validation rule's formula field.

So, for example, if you want your field match the regex, you should write the formula like this:

```
NOT(REGEX(CustomField__c, "[\\sa-zA-Z0-9.,:?;%/()\'!\"\"-]*"))
```

**Explanation**: add `NOT()`, therefore if the field matches regex it does not be caught as error condition.

Here is the link to documentation: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customize_functions_i_z.htm&type=5

Comment: I tried this. but now its not even allowing me to save when the value is just alphabets

Comment: [\\sa-zA-Z0-9.,:?;%/()\'!\"\"-]*